# Unable to load library libPS9Parser.so library permissions denied

Tags: redhat, libraries, rhel

I'm trying to run an application and the debug log is throwing this error:

ERROR: Unable to load /app/path/libPCL9Parser.so: 13 'Permission denied'
ERROR: Unable to load /app/path/libPS9Parser.so: 13 'Permission denied'.

The files exist and have 755 permissions on both files so I'm not sure why the libraries aren't loading.  Do I need to install another package or is there something up with the library config possibly?  Can I add the path to the library in one of the library configuration files like /etc/ld.so.conf.d/kernel-3.10.0-1160.92.1.el7.x86_64.conf??

Thanks for all of your input!